# Add All Folders Named "inc/" to Additional Include Path in Visual Studio 2022

Tags: c++, c, visual-studio, visual-studio-2022, include-path

I am working with a C project in Visual Studio 2022 Visual C++. There are multiple libraries included in the source code and all of them contain an `inc/` directory for header files. I am trying to add all of them to the "Project Property > Configuration Properties > C/C++ > General > Additional Include Directories". I am now using the wildcard `$(ProjectDir)**\inc` but VS still cannot find the header files. I have checked that this macro correctly expands to `C:\Path\To\My\Project\**\inc`.

What should I put instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Visual Studio C++ project does not support wildcards.

https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/project-item-capture-by-wildcard-is-broken/1030344

You could use a simple script and copy the result to `Project Property > Configuration Properties > C/C++ > General > Additional Include Directories`

PowerShell:

```
$result = Get-ChildItem -Path "C:\Path\To\My\Project\**\inc" -Directory | ForEach-Object { $_.FullName }
$resultString = $result -join ";"
Write-Host $resultString
```